# GIT: stuck with "fatal: pathspec ... did not match any files" :-(

Tags: git

I'm totally newbie with GIT, but in simple cases I've been using it to controll my website and changes made on it.
I've been using in my website librarry called "mpdf", which i've updated repleacing old files with new ones (strictly with manual of mpdf).
My website works fine, all works perfect.

Right now i'm trying to export archive to my live environment using command (as many times before):

```
git archive --output=export.zip --format=zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only #commit1 #commit2)
```

and then I became fatal error:

```
fatal: pathspec '5.7.4.txt' did not match any files
```

I've tried to locate this file, couse i don't know it and found that there weren't files with this name, only file with name "CHANGES 5.7.4.txt" is in subdirectory /libraries...

I have bare repository where i've pulled all committs, its only for backup in any case of problem.

I have even tried to make brand new copy of repository in new directory, but the problem in brand new directory still exists :-(

As I mentioned, im totally newbie, I'm only using few simple commands: git archive, git checkout, git branch, gitpull, git merge... Can You give me and advice, how to solve this strenge problem?